# 400 response without any context in AWS Appsync where Lambda is a Data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm getting the below response in AWS Appsync console, when i try to invoke graphql API.

```bash
Request failed with status code 400
```

Query:

```
query MyQuery {
  getUserData(inputArguments: $inputArguments) {
    __typename
  }
}
```

Variables:

```json
{
    "inputArguments": {
    }
}
```

I'm unable to debug it as Lambda is not being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely caused by insufficient rights. Does Appsync have the rights to call the Lambda function?

Somawhat *similar* problem discussed here
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19239

Excerpt code from the linked issue that was the solution. It grants appsync.amazonaws.com rights to call the 'authorizerLambda' lambda:

```
authorizerLambda.addPermission("appsync", {
  principal: new ServicePrincipal('appsync.amazonaws.com'),
  action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
})
```